# Retropie screen sharing

Tags: pi-3, retropie

I have a RPi 3 with Retropie installed. Since I do not have an HDMI monitor, I would like to know if there is a way to use my laptop (Macbook Air) in order to display the actual HDMI output of RPi. It is not my intention to use my laptop in order to take control of the RPi, but rather all the input will be given by controller connected to RPi and I just want the HDMI output to be shared with another monitor over a LAN. My laptop is connected via WiFi and RPi is connected via Ethernet to my router

Comment: Retropie runs outside of the Desktop environment so I'm not aware of any way to stream the output to a laptop. VNC would work if it was within the Desktop.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to run the emulators without RetroPie?

Comment: Yes, not as convenient though. Retropie website lists each emulator. Not sure if they will all work within desktop.